# Upgrading Kafka-client causes UnsupportedForMessageFormatException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

I wanted to upgrade the `spring-boot` version of my project from `2.4.4` to `2.6.7`. Because of this, the `kafka-client` version also increased from `2.6.0` to `3.0.1`. There were few other version upgrades but the only relevant one for the issue I am about to describe was `kafka-reactor` upgrade from `1.2.11.RELEASE` to `1.3.11`.
We load tested the change on our pre-production environment and it worked fine there. However, after release we started getting the following exception and had to rollback our release:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedForMessageFormatException: The message format version on the broker does not support the request.
```

Upon investigation we figured out that the only difference bewteen our pre-prod and prod Kafka setup was the message format version, `log.message.format.version`. In pre-prod it was `2.0` but in prod it was `0.10.0`.

What I don't understand is why a new `Kakfa-client` version won't work with an old broker version? Should it not be **backward-compatible**?

Is there any way I can fix it without actually changing the broker config?

Comment: No, the log format is not always backward compatible. Several notes and warnings here about it - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

Answer (score 1):

0.10.0 is ancient (if that's your broker version).

I am not sure, but perhaps with the new major version (3.0.x), they dropped support for really old brokers.

In any case, spring-kafka 2.8.5, which comes with Boot 2.6.7, also works with the 2.8.1 kafka-clients, so you could try downgrading to that version.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.1/reference/html/#update-deps

But you really need to look at moving your prod broker to a much newer version.

Comment: Related - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-724%3A+Drop+support+for+message+formats+v0+and+v1